# Tomcat / Scala / Lift: S.redirectTo redirects to wrong URL

Tags: scala, tomcat, lift

I'm writing a Lift application which works fine when I'm testing locally with Jetty. However, when I deploy the application to a remote server with Tomcat running, my redirects stop working. I deploy my application with a war, myapplicationname.war and it's accessible via http://myserver:8080/myapplicationname/

This is what I have in my code:
    S.redirectTo("/manage/project", () => S.notice("Your entry has been saved"))

Instead of being redirected to http://myserver:8080/myapplicationname/manage/project I'm redirected to http://myserver:8080**/myapplicationname/myapplicationname**/manage/project (myapplicationname doubled). Everything else (Menus, SHtml.links etc) work just fine on the remote server. What could be the problem?

Comment: which version of lift, are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Lift 2.4-M3 version, problem mentioned above might be associated with [this](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/tickets/1082-redirectresponse-duplicates-contextpath) Lift's open issue

Comment: Yes, that was it! I've downgraded to Lift 2.4-M1 (didn't test M2) and it works now. Thank you! :-)  Actually, I didn't expect to encounter a bug that is not caused by myself...

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly something to do with Lift's interpretation of the context. You dont say what version of Lift or Tomcat you're using, but I would recommend looking at `LiftRules.calculateContextPath`. That is the rule function that is used throughout Lift's internals to determine how to undertake the redirect & rewriting.

Failing that, you may well have something screwy in your Tomcat setup. Alas, you simply dont provide enough information to debug this.